# Store a file on server with curl command using post method like scp?

Tags: linux, curl, cat

Like this:

```
cat tmp.txt | curl --post domain.com/file-to-store
```

I want to store content of tmp.txt on my machine to server using only terminal.
Is it possible?

Comment: Are you not able to use `scp`?

Comment: I dont want to use ssh...Just 80/tcp...and no authentication

Comment: *why* don't you want to use SSH? If you're planning to use HTTP POST it means you'll need a daemon that speaks HTTP listening on port 80, which means a webserver because given your question I don't think you're up to coding your own, and the overhead of even the most barebones webserver is several orders of magnitude higher than that of `sshd`. If you're bothered by the authentication step you can use a pre-shared key instead.

Comment: That said, voting to leave open -- it's not actually a duplicate; it's just a very poorly worded [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use HTTP protocol to upload files to a server and also to use `curl` to do so from the command line.

But for this to work, you need the HTTP server to support file uploads (either natively or through an application running on that server), for that feature to be enabled and configured and typically you need some form of authentication/authorization to prevent unexpected uploads to your server. You might also need to deal with file and directory permissions to allow the web server or web app to write to the local filesystem when it receives an uploaded file.

If that is all in place, then you have two ways to use `curl` to upload files using HTTP:

1. PUT method:

This is the native "verb" for uploading files. One advantage is that the URL you use for the upload matches the one where the uploaded file is meant to be available at after the upload. But, as mentioned above, you need your server to support file uploads using this method for this to work.

If this is an option, use the following syntax:

```
cat tmp.txt | curl -T - domain.com/file-to-store
```

2. POST method:

This is a way to invoke an application running on the web server, one that might implement file uploads... In this case, you need to call the URL to the application itself, so you typically need to encode the expected target URL or filename as a separate argument ("field") passed in the POST request.

One advantage of this approach is that it's *typically* easier to install and configure a file upload application on a server (there are many simple solutions using CGI protocol to do so) than configuring a web server to accept PUT requests.

If this is an option, use a syntax such as:

```
curl -F file=@tmp.txt -F url=/file-to-store domain.com/fileupload.cgi
```

Note that the example above is not literal and it's just an illustration of a hypothetical file upload application... The actual details would depend on which file upload application you decide to use and have available. The point of the example is to illustrate the use of curl's `-F` argument and the use of `@` to include the contents of a local file while using it.

See the [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) for more details, particularly the section on "Uploading" which describes the PUT method. It also mentions using POST as an option.